# How to serialize multiple select values, which were built into a $ each loop

Tags: javascript, jquery, serialization, each

My App have a $each loop, who's build the HTML with the values bringit from database.

```
$.each( result, function(i, row) {
        $('#pedidos').append(''+
        '<div class="container static-notification-white-r">' +
                '<div class="switch-box">' +
                        '<span><strong>PEDIDO: </strong></span> <span class="pedido text-highlight highlight-red">'+result[i].id+'</span>' +
                        '<span><strong>BAIRRO: </strong></span> <span class="uppercase">'+result[i].local+'</span>' +
                        '<span><strong>TEMPO RESTANTE: </strong></span> <span class="uppercase">'+result[i].created_on+'</span>' +
                        '<select class="selectMissao" data-role="flipswitch" onchange="">' +
                                '<option value="-'+result[i].id+'"></option>'+
                                '<option value="'+result[i].id+'"></option>'+
                        '</select>'+
                '</div>' +
        '<div>');
}
```

How to serialize all Select values, to send to another function?

I have tried to do anything like this, but doesn't work:

```
console.log('SELECT 1: '+$("#pedidos").find("selectMissao").serialize());
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this code

```
var getData= function(){
    var data = [];
    $.each($("#pedidos").find(".selectMissao"),function(i,v){
        data.push($(this).val());   
    });
    return data;
}

console.log(getData());
```

Comment: Thank you Rohit Bajaniya! That's the answer.